# Drupal , developing custom module, it is correct way am doing

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Below is the drupal custom modules,

can u please confirm it,

is it correct way of developing the custom module,

else please advise,

```
<?php
/**
*  Implementation of hook_form_alter().
*/
function register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
      case 'user_register': // the value we stole from the rendered form
        // your customizations go here
         // drupal_set_message('Hey, we\'ve tapped into this form!');
         $form['account']['bharani'] = array(
            '#title' => 'bharani',
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#description' => t(' bharanikumar custom field '),
          );
         $form['#submit'][] = 'register_submit_handler'; // Add this

      break;
  }
}

function register_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  $value = $form_state['values']['bharani'];
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $query  = "UPDATE users SET language='$value' WHERE mail='$mail'";
  db_query($query);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will not answer the *"correct way of developing the custom module"* part of the question, but here is a note about the way you're doing your SQL query :

You are using this :

```
$value = $form_state['values']['bharani'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$query  = "UPDATE users SET language='$value' WHERE mail='$mail'";
db_query($query);
```

With this, your code is subject to [**SQL-injections**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection) : no matter what the users will send into `$_POST['mail']`, it'll endup in the query, un-escaped !

With Drupal and [**`db_query()`**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6), you should, instead, use something like this :

```
$value = $form_state['values']['bharani'];
$mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];;
$query  = "UPDATE users SET language='%s' WHERE mail='%s'";
db_query($query, $value, $mail);
```

This way, Drupal will take care of the escaping, protecting you from SQL-injections.

Comment: thanks, am look good tutorial for drupal module customaisation , can u refer some free tutorial site/pdf

Comment: not really, sorry : I've mostly learnt going through the Drupal's website *(there are tons of documentation, there)*, and reading the code of other modules.

Comment: Aditionally, you should get the mail address also from $form_state and not $_POST.